# Error after update to 1.9.2.0 - item detail page

Tags: magento-1.9, error, magento-connect, fatal-error, varien

I've done a update to Magento 1.9.2.0 - still after the update I get the error message at my item detail page.

Have anyone a idea to fix the problem?

```
    Invalid method DerModPro_BasePrice_Block_Catalog_Product_View::cacheSelf(Array
(
)
)

Trace:
#0 [internal function]: Varien_Object->__call('cacheSelf', Array)
#1 [internal function]: DerModPro_BasePrice_Block_Catalog_Product_View->cacheSelf()
#2 /www/htdocs/w01325dc/oppacher-advent/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(348): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 /www/htdocs/w01325dc/oppacher-advent/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(214): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateAction(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#4 /www/htdocs/w01325dc/oppacher-advent/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /www/htdocs/w01325dc/oppacher-advent/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#6 /www/htdocs/w01325dc/oppacher-advent/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(113): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#7 /www/htdocs/w01325dc/oppacher-advent/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'no-route')
#8 /www/htdocs/w01325dc/oppacher-advent/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(75): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'no-route')
#9 /www/htdocs/w01325dc/oppacher-advent/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->noRouteAction()
#10 /www/htdocs/w01325dc/oppacher-advent/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('noRoute')
#11 /www/htdocs/w01325dc/oppacher-advent/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#12 /www/htdocs/w01325dc/oppacher-advent/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#13 /www/htdocs/w01325dc/oppacher-advent/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#14 /www/htdocs/w01325dc/oppacher-advent/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#15 {main}
```

Comment: Problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like one of your modules, `DerModPro_BasePrice`, might be incompatible with Magento 1.9.2.0.

Go into `etc/modules/DerModPro_BasePrice.xml` and change `<active>true</active>` to `<active>false</active>`

Clear the cache and recheck.

If this module is the problem you should contact the module developer and ask if there is an updated version.

Comment: Yes, I know. I have try this... but there is a new error: Fatal error: Call to a member function setData() on a non-object in /www/htdocs/w01325dc/oppacher-advent/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Config.php on line 651"

Comment: @Pino that one is most likely related to a config error. It doesn't give any module reference? magento updates are always a headache.

Comment: no, there is no reference. do you or anybody have no idea to fix the problem?

Comment: This is because the module added attributes which now reference non-existing attribute models. This link explains how to uninstall it completely: http://de.nr-apps.com/faq/content/21/92/de/wie-kann-baseprice-pro-vollstaendig-deinstalliert-werden.html